# esp-idf openocd with jtag could not start

Tags: esp32, esp-idf, openocd, jtag

I trying to setup esp32s3 project with JTAG with esp-idf but when start openocd, below error seen:

```
$openocd -f board/esp32s3-builtin.cfg
Open On-Chip Debugger v0.12.0-esp32-20230419 (2023-04-18-22:02)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : only one transport option; autoselecting 'jtag'
Info : esp_usb_jtag: VID set to 0x303a and PID to 0x1001
Info : esp_usb_jtag: capabilities descriptor set to 0x2000
Warn : Transport "jtag" was already selected
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Error: libusb_open() failed with LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS
Error: esp_usb_jtag: could not find or open device!
```

My USB port connected as:

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 303a:1001 Espressif USB JTAG/serial debug unit
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 10c4:ea60 Silicon Labs CP210x UART Bridge
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Anyone have any idea how to solve it?
Thanks!